# How to simulate a martingale process problem in R?

Tags: r, random, simulation

100 people are watching a theater.At the end of the show  all of them are visiting the vesting room in order to take their coats.The man working on the vesting room give back people's coat totally at random.The participants that they will pick the right coat leave.The other that have picked the wrong one, give back the coat and the man again randomly gives back the coat.The process ends when all the customers of the theater take back their right coat.

I want to simulate in R this martingale process in order to find the expected time that this process will end.
But I don't know how .Any help ?
Something like:

```
# 100 customers
x = seq(1,100,by=1);x
# random sample from x 
y = sample(x,100,replace=FALSE)
x==y
# for the next iteration exclude those how are TRUE and run it again until everyone is TRUE
```

The expected time is how many iterations where needed .

Or something like this :

```
n = 100
X = seq(1,100,by=1)
martingale = rep(NA,n)

iterations = 0
accept     = 0
while (X != n) {
  iterations =  iterations + 1
  y = sample(1:100,100,replace=FALSE)
  if (X = y){ 
    accept = accept + 1
    X = X+1
    martingale [X] = y
  }
}
accept
iterations
```

Comment: The clearest but not necessarily most efficient solution to this problem will involve running a `while` loop to simulate the process; each time through the loop, sample the current customer and the current coat and use an `if` statement to update the list of customers and coats accordingly (leave them unchanged if not matching, otherwise remove the customer from the list/vector of customers and the coat from the list/vector of coats)

Comment: OK, the solution you just added looks reasonable. Does it work? If not, what does it do?

Comment: @BenBolker no it does not work of course.I made it just like a pseudo code.But your description looks nicer.Still I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @BenBolker you are saying that there will be two vectors: a) the customers and b)the coats.And each time I must exclude the matching from both vectors.The process will end when both vectors will be empty.Right?I was thinking having one vector and removing each iterative match.But I don't know if I am right.

Comment: Yes, I think you could do it with one vector.  You would take two samples `i`  and `j` from the vector that was left, independently; if `i == j` then `remaining <- remaining[-i]`.

Comment: still is diffract for me.But thanks for your help Ben

Comment: You state your goal is "to find the expected time that this process will end," but at no point in your problem description do you say what how long any of the actions or interactions take.  It sounds like person `i` would undergo `k` interactions with the clerk, where `k` has a geometric distribution with `p = 1 / i` for `i` = 1,...,100.

Comment: The number of iterations needed are the average steps until the process will end.It's not geometric distribution.The person `i` will undergo `k` exchanges with the clerk until he/she finds his/her `j` coat.if `I==j`.But I don't care about `k` interactions.I want to count the iterations needed until all `i==j`.

Comment: @HungryHomer I believe you're mistaken in stating it's not geometric. Consider the `i`th person from the back of the line.  That means `100 - i` folks have already gotten their coats, and there are `i` coats remaining. If the clerk behaves completely randomly, that means the probability that the customer gets their own coat is a constant `p = 1 / i` on each attempt.  If the attempts are independent, that's the very [definition of a geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Definitions). So either it's geometric, or your explanation is incomplete.

Comment: All right.What a person does is geometric distribution.But here is a martingale process.You have to look the process not what a person does.If there was only one person then the process would be a markovian but the each effort would be geometrically distributed.

Comment: No, "what a person does" is **not** a geometric distribution. The number of interactions a person has with the clerk has a geometric distribution. The total time to clear all people will be a function of how many interactions there are in total.  Further, if there were only one person the process is not markovian because it is deterministic - there's only one coat so the clerk picks it with probability 1, and the transaction is complete with one interaction. And with that, I will bow out of the discussion.

Comment: @pjs, one way to convince the OP would to have them do the brute-force simulation and compare an ensemble of the results to a geometric distribution ...

Comment: isolate from the process one person.Then think again.Is markovian.Thanks for participating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows (using 10 people as an example, the print statement is unnecessary, just to show what's done in each iteration):

```
set.seed(0)
x <- 1:10
count <- 0
while(length(x) > 0){
  x <- x[x != sample(x)]
  print(x)
  count <- count + 1
}

# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 10
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7 9
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# [1] 3 6
# 
count
# [1] 10
```

For each step in the loop, it removes the values of x where the customers have been randomly allocated their coat, until there are none left.

To use this code to get the expected time taken for 100 people, you could extend it to:

```
set.seed(0)
nits <- 1000 #simulate the problem 1000 times
count <- 0
for (i in 1:nits){
  x <- 1:100
  while(length(x) > 0){
    x <- x[x != sample(x)]
    count <- count + 1/nits
  } 
}
count
# [1] 99.901
```

I hypothesise without proof that the expected time for n people is n iterations - it seems pretty close when I tried with 50, 100 or 200 people.

Comment: Very useful,simple and meaningful code but one question.From the 3rd up to the 9th iteration it found no match.Because 3,4,5,6,7 remain with no match.

Comment: Yes, just the luck of that random simulation that there were a few iterations with no correct allocations. If you want to find the expected time, you'd need to run the whole code many times (excluding the `set.seed`) and take the average count

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow your discussion above and I'm not entirely sure if that's what you want, but my rationale was as follows:

- You have N people and queue them.
- In the first round the first person has a chance of 1/N to get their clothes right.
- At this point you have two options. Eitehr person 1 gets their clothes right or not.
- If person 1 gets their clothes right, then person 2 has a chance of 1/(N-1) to get their clothes right. If person 1 didn't get the correct clothes, person 1 remains in the pool (at the end), and person 2 also has a 1/N probability to get their clothes right.
- You continue to assign thes probabilities until all N persons have seen the clerk once. Then you sort out those who have the right clothes and repeat at step 1 until everyone has their clothes right.
- For simulation purposes, you'd of course repeat the whole thing 1000 or 10000 times.

If I understand you correctly, you are interstes in the number of iterations, i.e. how often does the clerk have to go through the whole queue (or what remains of it) until everyone has their clothes.

library(tidyverse)

```
people <- 100
results <- data.frame(people     = 1:people,
                      iterations = NA)

counter <- 0
finished <- 0

while (finished < people)
{
  loop_people <- results %>%
    filter(is.na(iterations)) %>%
    pull(people)

  loop_prob <- 1/length(loop_people)
  loop_correct <- 0

  for (i in 1:length(loop_people))
  {
    correct_clothes_i <- sample(c(0,1), size = 1, prob = c(1-loop_prob, loop_prob))
    if (correct_clothes_i == 1)
    {
      results[loop_people[i], 2] <- counter + 1
      loop_correct <- loop_correct + 1
      loop_prob <- 1/(length(loop_people) - loop_correct)
    }
  }
  counter <- counter + 1
  finished <- length(which(!is.na(results$iterations)))
}

max(results$iterations)

[1] 86

head(results)

  people iterations
1      1          7
2      2         42
3      3         86
4      4         67
5      5          2
6      6          9
```

The `results$iterations` column contains the iteration number where each person has gotten their clothes right, thus `max(results$iterations)` gives you the total number of loops.

I have no proof, but empirically and intuitively the number of required iterations should approach N.

Comment: They are not in queue.There are all N=100 together.After the first matching there will be left say 97.And so on…The question is how many times the clerk randomly shared the coat until everyone got the right one.

Comment: But the clerk randomly picks some clothes, right? and then he shows it to one person at a time. If the clerk would show it ALL people at the same time, than you have a probability of 1 that in the first iteration someone would pick the right clothes. In the second iteration you again woudl have a probability of 1. But then you have exactly N iterations, but I don't think that#s what you want?

Comment: No.I am sorry for the confusion.The just gives the random coats to random people.If there is a match they leave.And process continues with the remainimg customers.

Comment: in that case, the solution from @Miff seems to be correct. But the theoretical results reminas the same. In the long run, you need N iterations until everyone has gotten the right clothes.